# Is it possible to detect floor with objects placed on it using ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I want to detect floor using ARkit , when objects are present such as table etc. and want to color the detected surface, is this possible using ARkit, I am a newbie in ARKit world and not sure if this is possible and where to start.

Comment: I am also newbie. but you can detect horizontal surface .and also put 3d object say SCNode to it with different colors

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yep know that thanks , but my doubt is about objects does ARKit detect surface below objects

Comment: Try the Apple's sample project for interaction and plane detection, we were able to use the same in our app to have a floor plan generator with ARKit

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question - do you want to detect a plane such as table, floor etc or do you want to know if it is possible to detect a plane UNDERNEATH objects - for example: detect a table eventhough it's full of different objects?

Comment: @JushKillaB detect floor when it’s having objects on it

Comment: @JushKillaB asking about floor occupied with objects I want to detect that not objects on table

Answer (score 7):

Your session configuration function should be like this, you call it on viewWillAppear

```
func setUpSceneView() {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

        sceneView.session.run(configuration)

        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
    }
```

you can also use .vertical for walls or whatever..

on view did load add a tapGestureRecognizer to the scene so that you can add the SCNNode where you tap to the detected surface

addTapGestureToSceneView() inside viewDidLoad

```
func addTapGestureToSceneView() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(placeOnSurface.addNodeToSceneView(withGestureRecognizer:)))
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
```

the method addNodeToSceneView will place SNNode on surface when it detects the plane..

```
@objc func addShipToSceneView(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
        let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)

        guard let hitTestResult = hitTestResults.first else { return }
        let translation = hitTestResult.worldTransform.translation
        let x = translation.x
        let y = translation.y
        let z = translation.z

        var name:String = "YourModel.obj" //you can add node whatever


        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("This is run on the background queue")

            let tempScene = SCNScene(named: name)!
            var geom:SCNGeometry = tempScene.rootNode.childNodes[0].geometry!
            var boxNode:SCNNode = SCNNode(geometry: geom)
            boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
            group.leave()

        }
        group.notify(queue: .main){
            //Here you know that the node is has been put
        }
    }

and you need some functions for render



    extension float4x4 {
    var translation: float3 {
        let translation = self.columns.3
        return float3(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
    }
}



    extension placeOnSurface: ARSCNViewDelegate {
        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            // 1
            guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

            // 2
            let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
            let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

            // 3
            plane.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.transparentLightBlue

            // 4
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

            // 5
            let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
            let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
            let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
            planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

            // 6
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }

        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            // 1
            guard let planeAnchor = anchor as?  ARPlaneAnchor,
                let planeNode = node.childNodes.first,
                let plane = planeNode.geometry as? SCNPlane
                else { return }

            // 2
            let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
            let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
            plane.width = width
            plane.height = height

            // 3
            let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
            let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
            let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
            planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
        }
    }
```

I also recommend you in viewDidLoad to call the function configureLighting() for better user experience

```
func configureLighting() {
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks and thats a lot of efforts for an answer :) , I assume there is a possibility to detect surfaces behind and beyond objects , I would certainly try this code .

Comment: Yes, if it doesn't detect surfaces you can't do something, it will be like writing your own library and sometimes it works better with more lighting

Comment: guard let hitTestResult = hitTestResults.first else { return }
always goes in else condition (always return)
Can you please check if it same goes for you.
Thanks.

Comment: It must first detect a plane and then it will pass the condition, try enable the debug option to see the planes that are being created in the scene to be sure that a plane has been detected and tap on the plane. Then it will pass the condition and you will get the position inside the plane

Comment: func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) Never called may this is the reason.

Comment: Have you set the delegate of the scene view to self?

Comment: @ Βασίλης Δ 
https://github.com/appcoda/ARKitPhysics
Please download the Full-Demo Project and run on the device, its not working on my device. .

Comment: it works fine my friend 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qG78qtC3pgyHSlJF783ul-RcQ60enAfi/view?usp=sharing
check if you have rejected the camera usage, restart your device an reinstall the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169727/discussion-between-jatin-vashisht-and--).